# Free Windows hosting control panel

Tags: windows, hosting

Is there any free/open source  hosting control panel available for windows 2003/2008 , I am not asking about limited freeware like dot net panel/plesk  ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://windowshostingc.sourceforge.net/ - open source one

Comment: this looks interesting but the site could use a color change IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

DotNetPanel has ceased development and transitioned to an open source model under the product name / branding of WebSitePanel.  I haven't tried it yet, but probably will soon.  http://www.websitepanel.net/

Answer (score 0):

[ZPanel](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zpanel/) is free hosting control panel that works with both windows and Linux.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.dotnetpanel.com/dotnetpanel/pricing-matrix/

I've tested it and for free it's pretty darn good. The paid upgrades are reasonable especially compared to Plesk or Ensim.

Comment: -1... you obviously missed the part of them stopping devlopment an making it OPEN SOURCE under the name websitepanel (http://www.websitepanel.net/).